# Trying to remove the time portion of date stamps in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I found a sub that removes the time portion of a date/time stamp from a range that works but it takes a lot of time when that range gets large.

This code works but is slow:

```
Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long

LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LR
    With shRawData.Range("B" & i)
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
        .Value = DateValue(.Value)
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

So I tried to put the range into an array and remove tie time portion there but I keep getting a run-time error 424: Object required error.  I clearly am not understanding something kind of basic.
Here is the code that fails

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Temp As Date
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  ' Last row of source worksheet
    
    Dim DateTime As Variant
    DateTime = Application.Transpose(shRawData.Range("B2:B" & LastRow))
    
    For i = LBound(DateTime) To UBound(DateTime)
        DateTime(i).Value = DateValue(DateTime(i).Value)
    Next i
    
    ' Write data to Sheet
    shRawData.Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Value = Application.Transpose(DateTime)

End Sub
```

If you know what I'm doing wrong can you please explain what I'm doing wrong.

Thanx

Comment: why are you transposing just to transpose back.  just deal with it as a 2D array.

Comment: Hi Scott, Some time ago when I started found that using arrays would save me time I found a code sample that did it that way, so I just continued doing that.  What is the proper way to copy an array to a range on your spreadsheet?

Comment: See the answer below.  It does not use the `Application.Transpose`  If the range from which you are grabbing the data is the same shape as the range to which you will apply the result there is no reason to use it.  It has a limitation that is very easy to reach.  It is better in my opinion to just deal with 2D arrays when working with data that is coming and/or going to the worksheet.

Comment: Re _If you know what I'm doing wrong_ - an array doesn't have a `Value` property  (actually it doesn't have properties at all, it's not an object). So your line should be `DateTime(i) = DateValue(DateTime(i))`.  That said, see Fane's answer for a better solution

Answer (score 1):

Your code about you appreciate as being slow, does not eliminate any time. It only changes the `Date` format. If you need to make some calculations, the original time (double) will be taken in consideration. If this does not bother you it si enough to use

```
   shRawData.Range("B2:B" & LR).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
```

without any iteration. If you really need to eliminate the time of **each cell**, you should use:

```
Sub ElimTime()
 Dim shRawData As Worksheet, LR As Long, rngB As Range, arr, i As Long

 Set shRawData = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary sheet if shRawData is not the sheet codeName
 LR = shRawData.Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 Set rngB = shRawData.Range("B2:B" & LR) 'set the range to be processed
 arr = rngB.Value2               'place the range in an array for faster iteration
 rngB.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"  'format the Date range as needed

 'eliminate the decimal part to let only the `Date` remaining
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
     arr(i, 1) = Fix(arr(i, 1))
 Next i
 rngB.Value2 = arr 'Drop the array content at once
End Sub
```

Excel keeps `Date` as numeric. `Date` without time is kept as `Long` and `Date` with time inclusive as `Double`. So, you need to eliminate the decimal part...

Comment: `CLng` does not **remove** the time (or, as you comment `eliminate the decimal part`). Rather it **Rounds** the value (using the same method as the VBA.Round method). If you want to **remove** the time, you should probably use `Int` (or possibly `Fix`)

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld Yes, you are right. I rapidly thought that `Long` not accepting decimals will trunk the number eliminating the decimals. I even pseudo test it, but on an example with decimals less than 5... I will replace `CLng` with `Fix`. Thanks!